# HOw can i do that partial match in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying this

```
    $("ul.nav-tabs a:contains('profile')").parent().addClass("active")
```

It don't work if i have `Profile` in there.

Is there any way to make that `case insensitive`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for text of `a` then use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$("ul.nav-tabs a").filter(function() {
  if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == "profile")
       return $(this).parent();
}).addClass("active");
```

Comment: Eh? `:has()` filters DOM elements and not text.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `:contains` selector:

```
$("ul.nav-tabs a").filter(function() {
    return /profile/i.test($.text(this));
}).parent().addClass("active");
```

Comment: @user192362127 Like that: `return new RegExp(page, "i").test($.text(this));`.

Comment: I tried it didn't work, no js error but tab didn't got selected